# Android - How do implement ListViewAnimation to an existing ListView?

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I have a ListView that its contents are populated from a remote server. It's a simple ListView created by following tutorials you normally found on blogs. Recently, I've found out [ListViewAnimation](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) and would like to use it in my project.

I already have a Listview, now how do I implement the listviewanimation library in the existing one?

I have tried to follow the [wiki](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/wiki/Appearance-Animations) on github, but still couldn't make through it.

Here is my `ListView` activity:

```
public class CategoryActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

        ListView lv = getListView();


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                // when item is clicked, go to its corresponding details
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ItemListActivity.class);
                String category_id = ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.category_id)).getText()
                        .toString();
                i.putExtra("category_id", category_id);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        new LoadCategories().execute();
    }

    class LoadCategories extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(Constants.URL_CATEGORY, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Categories JSON: ", "> " + json);

            try {
                categories = new JSONArray(json);

                if (categories != null) {
                    // looping through All albums
                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item values in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT, songs_count);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        categoryList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("Categories: ", "null");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    // populate each row with json data
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            CategoryActivity.this, categoryList,
                            R.layout.custom_list_category, new String[] {
                                    TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT },
                            new int[] { R.id.category_id, R.id.category_name,
                                    R.id.songs_count });

                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

This is the `layout.xml` for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="15dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see in the code, the list is customized and is populated by the SimpleAdapter.

Can anyone guide me on how to implement the ListViewAnimation library into my project here?

---

**EDIT**

Here is my new ListActivity. I've modified the AsyncTask onPostExecute part. The problem now is doesn't display anything. Just a blank screen:

```
public class CategoryActivity extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);


            // Check toast which user is logged in
            userDetails = db.getUserDetails().get("name").toString();

            setTitle(userDetails);

            // Hashmap for ListView
            categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            new LoadCategories().execute();

            // get listview
            ListView lv = getListView();

            //lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.category_list);
            lv.setDivider(null);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ItemListActivity.class);

                    String category_id = ((TextView) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.category_id)).getText()
                            .toString();
                    i.putExtra("category_id", category_id);

                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
    }

    class LoadCategories extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CategoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Listing Categories...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(Constants.URL_CATEGORY, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Categories JSON: ", "> " + json);

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
            try {
                categories = new JSONArray(json);

                if (categories != null) {
                    // looping through All albums
                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item values in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT, songs_count);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        categoryList.add(map);
                    }

                    mAdapter = new CategoryListAdapter(CategoryActivity.this, categoryList);
                    AnimationAdapter animAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(mAdapter);
                    animAdapter.setAbsListView(getListView());
                    getListView().setAdapter(animAdapter);

                    // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    Log.d("Categories: ", "null");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`CategoryListAdapter` class:

```
public class CategoryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>{
        private Context mContext;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> urls;
        HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

        public CategoryListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items) {
            /*super(items);
            mContext = context;*/
            this.mContext = context;

            urls = items;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return getItem(position).hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView item_name;
            TextView item_count;
            TextView item_id;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_category, parent, false);

            resultp = urls.get(position);

            item_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
            item_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songs_count);
            item_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_id);

            item_name.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_NAME));
            item_count.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT));
            item_id.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_ID));

            return view;
        }
}
```

Comment: Which property of the lib you want to use?

Comment: You mean which animation? Specifically, the Alpha adapter listview.

Comment: Check my second answer..and let me know if anything else required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try setting layout animation to your existing list view.
For ex:

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
Animation animation =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
            R.anim.fadeout);
set.addAnimation(animation);
LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(
        set, 0.5f);
<Your_list_view>.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

This will set `R.anim.fadeout` animation to every item of the list.

**EDIT**
Try this

Save this xml in anim folder(this is fed-in effect)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

And in createView

```
ListView lv = getListView();

AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
Animation animation =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
            R.anim.fadein);
set.addAnimation(animation);
LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(
        set, 0.5f);
lv.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

And remove AnimationAdapterCode

Answer (score 2):

Have you done this --

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, 1, notificationList );
        AnimationAdapter animAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
        animAdapter.setAbsListView(listView);
        listView.setAdapter(animAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must fix your `onPostExecute()`. That runs on the main or UI thread. You don't need the `runOnUiThread()` inside `onPostExecute()`.

Now, coming to how do we use the library part: you would add the jar file to your project under libs folder and make sure that it's also linked when you are building the apk. The steps to add the library depends on which IDE you are using - Eclipse or Android-Studio.

If the jar file is not immediately available, then you might have to build that first from the github link you have.

Finally, on the githib, there is an [examples](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/tree/master/example) folder. That should tell you exactly how to exercise the ListViewAnimations library.

HTH.

Comment: Imported the all the libs. I've also followed the examples folder, tried to strip off things I don't want (such as the actionbar). I guess, mine is a bit complicated for using an AsyncTask to retrieve data from the server and populate it into the listview?

Comment: So, you are able to see the data in a nice custom list view. What's not working is just the animation part?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your adapter change with following and make me know that its working or not.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CategoryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>
{
    private Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> urls;


    public CategoryListAdapter(Context context,int res, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items) {
        super(context, res); 
        this.mContext = context;
        urls = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return urls.size();
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row1, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
            holder.item_count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songs_count);
            holder.item_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_id);     
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        resultp = urls.get(position);
        holder.item_name.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_NAME));
        holder.item_count.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT));
        holder.item_id.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_ID));

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView item_name;
        TextView item_count;
        TextView item_id;
    }
}
```