# Android ListViewAnimations NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, listview

I am attempting to add ListViewAnimations to my List View and the instructions seem pretty straight forward. Pretty much plugin and play right?

So I take of my original code of:

```
UsersAdapter adapter =
                new UsersAdapter(DingggActivity.this, DingggActivity.friendTempList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This works great. Everything updates and displays as needed. But when I modify the code to work with the ListViewAnimations i get this error:

```
09-10 17:19:52.083    2125-2125/com.dingggapp.dinggg E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dingggapp.dinggg, PID: 2125
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator[]
            at com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.appearance.AnimationAdapter.animateViewIfNecessary(AnimationAdapter.java:174)
            at com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.appearance.AnimationAdapter.getView(AnimationAdapter.java:145)
```

Isn't this usually an error of the classes not be imported correctly. I thought it did this correctly.

Here is my new adapter code after adding the ListViewAnimations.

```
UsersAdapter adapter =
                new UsersAdapter(DingggActivity.this, DingggActivity.friendTempList);
AlphaInAnimationAdapter animationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
animationAdapter.setAbsListView(listView);
listView.setAdapter(animationAdapter);
```

I also tried out all of the responses from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463649/android-how-do-implement-listviewanimation-to-an-existing-listview) but none of them worked for me either. I'm not sure if this makes a difference but it might be worth noting that I am creating and updating the adapters and listViews from within a Firebase event (more specifically `onChildAdded` and `onChildChanged`).

Comment: What helped me (but I am not pleased with such solution so will look for a better one) is to add the dependency inside build.gradle
`compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'`